# Python: Creating a Regex function with optional flags

Tags: python, regex

I have a function that returns a list of tuples that describe the start and end point of any occurences of a substring in a string.

```
def findlist(input, place):
    return [m.span() for m in re.finditer(input, place)]
```

Therefore `findlist('a', 'abcabc')` returns `[(0, 1), (3, 4)]`.

Is there a way to optionally add in an argument for flags to this function? Below is my attempt, I've added in `flags=None` but that raises the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'NoneType' and 'int'` There doesn't seem to be a flag for "no flags" so is there a way to do what I'm looking for?

```
def findlist(input, place, flags=None):
    return [m.span() for m in re.finditer(input, place, flags=flags)]
```

Comment: What is the expected result ?

Comment: In Python3.x, `re.UNICODE` is used by default, you may use this one. But all of them are initialized as ints, so using `0` will work. `SRE_FLAG_TEMPLATE = 1 # template mode (disable backtracking)
SRE_FLAG_IGNORECASE = 2 # case insensitive
SRE_FLAG_LOCALE = 4 # honour system locale
SRE_FLAG_MULTILINE = 8 # treat target as multiline string
SRE_FLAG_DOTALL = 16 # treat target as a single string
SRE_FLAG_UNICODE = 32 # use unicode "locale"
SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE = 64 # ignore whitespace and comments
SRE_FLAG_DEBUG = 128 # debugging
SRE_FLAG_ASCII = 256 # use ascii "locale"`

Comment: The [default value for `flags`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) is simply `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to

```py
def findlist(input, place, flags=0):
    return [m.span() for m in re.finditer(input, place, flags=flags)]
```

Then it will work since flags default value for `re.finditer` method is 0.